# How to place image side by side on desktop mode but image above the text on Mobile?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float, responsive, mobile-website

I want to add an image to my website such that it floats left to text on maximum resolution ie; `@media (max-width:1200px)`
But It should be on top of text when in mode of a mobile device ie; `@media (max-width:360px)`

Like below image

[image]

Here lines represent text and (image) stands for image.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {}
```

Tell me if its work !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css for the image. Also the other element beside the image will have the same css for max-width 1200px.

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    img {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
    img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope it will work for you

<style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    img {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
        float: right;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

</style>
<p>In this example, the image will float to the right in the paragraph, and the text in the paragraph will wrap around the image.</p>

<img src="https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2018/04/25/PicsArt_04-25-08.29.07.png" alt="Pineapple"><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>
```

Comment: Helped me a lot , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some screens will be higher than 1200px ranging from 1280px to 1920px instead of using:

```
@media (max-width:1200px) {}
@media (max-width:360px) {}
```

I'd suggest you do it this way:

```
@media (min-width:360px) {}
@media (max-width:360px) {}
```

This is much better way as it will take 100% width of the element as long as device screen is greater than 360px.